# How to use locate to search for folders only

Tags: unix, locate

On a UNIX system, "locate" searches the database for files with chosen name or files within the folder with the chosen name.
How can I use locate to output only folders, not files?

Comment: See also [that similar question on unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192739)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with this solution:

```
locate -i "$foldername" | while read line
        do
            if [[ -d "$line" && `echo ${line##*/} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` = *`echo $foldername | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`* ]]; then
                echo "$line"
            fi
        done
```

Comment: Can you explain what the echo ${line##*/} is doing?

Comment: @user128063 It's a bit late but anyway… It trims the string up to the last `/`. In general, `${var##pattern}` trims the longest match from the beginning in `$var`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Answer (score 17):

Actually, `locate` has what it takes if you use the `--regexp` option and you don't mind it spitting out files that have the same name as the directories you seek.  The "end of line" position marker gets the job done:

```
locate -r '/dirname$'
```

`locate` also supports `--ignore-case` if that's what you want.

Comment: To search for all directories, `locate -r '/[^\.]*$'`.

Comment: Mateen's approach doesn't filter for directories. It returns everything in the database. The OP was looking for a specific directory and seems to know the name of the directory he wants.

Comment: Doesn't work if `dirname` is in the middle of the dir name.

Comment: @CodyChan: I was assuming "dirname" is the entire directory name. Can you show an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: `string` is part of the directory name such as I need to search directory whose name contains `def` such as directory "abc_def_ghi" since most of the time I need to locate a directory containing a string, just like locating a file containing a word but it is a directory.

Comment: This seems wrong.
If you have a file called `/foo` and a directory called `/d/foo`, command `locate -r /foo$` will match both.

Comment: @sancho You are correct. That's why my "answer" from 6 years ago had the condition "if...you don't mind it spitting out files that have the same name as the directories you seek." The mlocate database doesn't distinguish files and folders. Therefore, even if you had a built-in check, it would still have to refer to the actual directory entry to see if it is a directory, a file, pipe, device, or whatever.

Comment: try
locate -r '.*DIRNAME[^/]$'

This will search for DIRNAME which is in middle of a ORIGINALDIRNAME.

Answer (score 4):

`locate` itself can't do it for you. So the UNIX way to do it is to filter the output of `locate`:

```
locate --null something | xargs -r0 sh -c 'for i do [ -d "$i" ] && printf "%s\n" "$i"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: @sch Wow, that sucks

Comment: The proper way is with something like `locate --null something | xargs -r0 sh -c 'for i do [ -d "$i" ] && printf "%s\n" "$i"; done' sh {} +`. `{}`  should never be embedded in the shell code, that's as bad as using `eval` with arbitrary data (hence the downvote).

Comment: Note that `[ -d` also returns true for symlinks to directories. Not necessarily bad, just worth noting as it's different for instance from `find -type d`.

Comment: @sch: Well, if you don't understand the consequences and if you're in the habit of having files named `$(reboot)` on your computer, maybe you shouldn't run commands you find on the internet with `sudo` ;D But, thanks for providing a better version, feel free to edit or post it as an answer, so it doesn't get lost in comments.

Comment: Unix systems are multi-user and /tmp is world-writable (and even on single user systems, you or a network service can be tricked into creating files named like that). Embedding that `{}` like that is a bug easily upgradable to a security vulnerability. IMO, on public Q&A websites, we should at least point out the limitations. Feel free to include that code in your answer. I'm generally not contributing to [SU], I just got there from a link on [unix.SE].

Comment: @sch: You definitely have a point, thanks for the improved code.

Comment: Hi @sch, how does `sh -c '…' sh {} +` differ from `sh -c '…' -- {}`? What does the plus sign do?

Comment: @ArchStanton, my bad, the `{} +` is for `-exec ... {} +`, not for xargs

Comment: @sch So the command would be `locate --null something | xargs -r0 sh -c '…' sh {}`?

Comment: @ArchStanton, drop the {} as well. See man xargs and man find. I've submitted an edit suggestion. It's pending revew atm

Comment: @sch So if I understood correctly your command is equivalent to `locate --null something | xargs -I{} -r0 sh -c '[ -d "$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$1"' sh {}`, right?

Comment: @ArchStanton, close,  though that would be less efficient as that would run one `sh` per file. There's also the question of `xargs` overall exit status. Using proper `if` constructs and do a `exit 255` if `printf` fails so `xargs` aborts as well may be preferable.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing @sch? What's the difference between using `xargs` and `locate --null something | while read -d $'\0' line; do …; done`? Is one preferable over the other?

Comment: @ArchStanton, that should be `while IFS= read -rd '' line`. `-d $'\0'` would make sense in zsh,  not in bash where it's the same as `''`. In any case, zsh also treats `-d ''` the same as `-d $'\0'`

Comment: @sch I figured out later that it was working because of an `IFS=` I had issued earlier. As far as I can tell, `while IFS= read -rd '' line` removes the newlines from the file names it gets as input: if I use it to just `echo` back the output of `locate --null`, file names with newlines are printed with a space instead of the newline. On  the other hand `while IFS=; read -rd ''`, with a semicolon, preserves the newlines in the output of echo, but I'm not sure about how it works…

Comment: @ArchStanton, you probably forgot to quote some parameter expansions, like using `echo $var` instead of `printf '%s\n' "$var"`. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) (also: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803))

Comment: @sch > _you probably forgot to quote some parameter expansions_. You're right. Thanks man for all the help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the find command ?

```
find . -name YOUR_SEARCH_NAME -type d
```

Comment: locate is faster and I don't need it to be up to date all the time for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

`find` as suggested in Scott Wilson's answer is what I would have used. However, if you really need to use the locate DB, a hackish solution could be

```
sudo strings /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db | grep -E '^/.*dirname'
```

- `sudo` since the database is not directly readable by regular users.
- `strings` to strip metadata (this makes you also find directories to which you don't have read permission, which `locate` usually hinders).
- `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` is the DB path on Ubuntu, apparently (as an example. Other distributions might have it in other places, e.g. `/var/lib/slocate/slocate.db`).
- `grep -E` to enable regular expressions.
- `^/.*dirname` will match all lines that start with a `/`, which all directories in the DB happen to do, followed by any character a number of times, followed by your search word.

Positive sides of this solution:

- it is faster than `find`,
- you can use all the bells and whistles of `grep` (or other favourite text processing tools).

Negative sides:

- the same as `locate` in general (DB must be updated),
- you need root access.

Comment: Yeah root access for a task like this should really be avoided.

Comment: Does this list matching files as well as matching directories?

Answer (score 2):

Putting Oliver Salzburg's neat line into your `.bashrc`:

```
# locate directories:
# -------------------
locd () {
    locate -0 -b -A "$@" | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c '[ -d "{}" ] && echo "{}"'
}
```

then you can type `locd something` everytime you want to locate just directories.

---

Some breakdown:

- `-0` provides better support for filenames containing spaces or newlines.
- `-b` or `--basename` matches only the last part of the path.
- `-A` matches all inputs, so if you provide multiple arguments, all must be present.

Comment: For me, to handle spaces in directories better, I use the following: `locate -i --all $1 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'if [ -d "'"{}"'" ]; then echo "'"{}"'"; fi'`

Comment: Use locate -0 and xargs -0 flags if you get the xargs unterminated quote error.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a little old but mlocate's limitations always bothered me too.  I finally created my own version of slocate/mlocate called `blocate` that uses sqlite for indexing and lets you index anything you want using a `find` command.  Performs really well and manages parallel indexing+searching with sqlite in just about 30 lines of bash. GPL - feedback welcome.

https://github.com/jboero/blocate

Hope this helps someone.  I built a personal archive website for my backups indexing with mlocate but I got tired of searches taking forever and I didn't want to build a full database solution around it.  My searches have gone from ~10s or so down to about 300ms.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of GNU find (4.9 or above), you can do something like:

```
locate -0 '*/dirname' | find -files0-from - -prune -type d
```

That is, pass the list of files from the locate cache to `find` which further filters it by type.

Replace `-type` with `-xtype` to also report symlinks eventually resolving to files of type *directory* like `[`'s or `[[...]]`'s `-d` does.

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
files=( ${(0)"$(locate -0 '*/dirname')"} )
dirs=( $^files(N/) )
```

Were we use the `/` glob qualifier to do the filtering by type (replace with `-/` to also include symlinks to directories). Or in one go:

```
files=( ${(0)^"$(locate -0 '*/dirname')"}(N/) )
```

`print` them `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn with:

```
print -rC1 -- $files
```

For instance.

Comment: In my system (Fedora 37, GNU findutils 4.9.0) I can only use `-files0-from -`, without the equal sign.

Comment: @ArchStanton, thanks. Fixed now. I guess I got confused with the `--files0-from=-` option of other GNU utilities like sort/wc/du.

Answer (score 0):

Place these as last lines or where ever it fits best for you.
gedit ~/.bashrc 


 `` #system only

slocate() { locate $@ | egrep -v ˆ/home ; }


 #system directories only

dslocate() { for directory in `locate $@ | egrep -v ˆ/home`; do if [ -d "$directory" ]; then echo $directory; fi; done ; }


 #whole system directories only

dlocate() { for directory in `locate $@`; do if [ -d "$directory" ]; then echo $directory; fi; done ; }


 #local user's only

llocate() { locate $@ | egrep ˆ/home ; }


 #local user's directories only

ldlocate() { for directory in `locate $@ | egrep ˆ/home`; do if [ -d "$directory" ]; then echo $directory; fi; done ; } ``

hope this helps, cheers

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the inverse of [this other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634209/137608).
Use

```
file $(locate -r 'xfce4-keyboard-overlay$') | grep directory$ | awk -F: '{ $(NF--)=""; print }'
```

Explanation:

1. `locate ...` finds all files and directories
2. `file $(...)` appends a message at the end of each line with the type of file
3. `grep ...` filters lines containing `directory$`
4. `awk ...` removes what `file ...` appended

Answer (score 0):

A small variation on others

```
for f in $(locate /dirname | grep /dirname$ ) ; do if [ -f $f ] ; then ls -1 $f ; fi ; done
```

If you want to match a pattern instead of providing the full name, there are also variations with `grep`.